# Application Crash with Heroku, Mongoid, and MongoHQ

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, mongoid, mongohq

I am trying to get my application online and functioning with Heroku.

The application uses MongoHQ and Mongoid.

I have read multiple guides that just say to add this, "uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>" to the mongoid.yml file, but it's not working for me.

This is the error I get from Heroku,

"Application Error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

This is what it's in my $ heroku logs

2011-03-12T21:09:57-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET autommator.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-03-12T21:09:57-08:00heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 76.112.220.158 | 795 | http | 503

Here is my mongoid.yml file.

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler= 'syck'

defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  # slaves:
  #   - host: slave1.local
  #     port: 27018
  #   - host: slave2.local
  #     port: 27019

development:
  <<: *defaults
  host: localhost
  database: autommator_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  host: localhost
  database: autommator_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
```

Completely out of ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem this morning.  My app on my development PC is running Ruby 1.9.2.  Heroku defaults to 1.8.7.

I just ran the commands found in this article, http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bamboo reloaded, and everything works.

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

To use mongoid with the Heroku add-on, your mongoid.yml should look like this:

```
production:
  uri: <%= ENV['MONGOHQ_URL'] %>
```

You shouldn't have any other database connection information there, so pull out the host, port, username, password and database fields.

Comment: @Paul-Elliot Sadly, the Application continues to crash.

I did some more digging in the logs and there is a "/home /config/boot.rb:3: uninitialized constant YAML::ENGINE (NameError)" there.

I don't know of that's helpful.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice the require at the top of the file. Try deleting the first two lines. I suspect that is your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help Paul, however I figured out the solution and it wasn't in the yml file.

"I figured out the problem this morning. My app on my development PC is running Ruby 1.9.2. Heroku defaults to 1.8.7.

I just ran the commands found in this article, http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bamboo reloaded, and everything works.

Thanks for the help guys."

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the database through the Heroku addon or directly from MongoHQ? If you did it directly from MongoHQ then you will need to set the variables manually.

```
heroku config:add MONGOHQ_URL=mongodb://user:pass@server.mongohq.com:port/db_name
```

If it was via the heroku addon then it should be created for you. If adding the variable doesn't help send us a support ticket to support@mongohq.com and we can dig further.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm stating the obvious here, but what that's doing is pulling the values of those from the environment.  In order for that to work, you would need to have set the variables (MONGOHQ_URL, etc) in the heroku environment.  I think the command for that is something like `heroku config:add MONGOHQ_URL=XXXXX` or something like that.  Definitely look it up in the heroku docs.

Given that you're getting the values out of the environment, though, the YML seems the wrong way to go.  I suggest and initializer file that just sets these value, or puts them into some sort of MONGO_CONFIG where you can read them anywhere.  If you go this route, you could also set them to the env variables if preset, or fall back to the YML file if not.

This railscast shows kind of what I'm talking about http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file  The difference is that when it comes time to set the variable, you set it to `ENV['XXX'] if ENV['XXX']`

Comment: the MONGOHQ_URL value is set in the heroku environment when the MongoHQ addon is installed.  Which should be enough information to connect to the MongoHQ remote database.

Comment: Have you verified they're all there?  Just writing code that prints them out or something?  That's what I would do anyway.  That said, as a developer, I wouldn't think to look in a yml file for code.

Comment: @John-Hinnegan I ran a heroku config --long and confirmed MongoHQ is installed and I have a MongoHQ account/remote database.

I can not write output code because the application is crashing when run on heroku.  This is the output:

2011-03-12T21:09:57-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET autommator.heroku.com/ dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0 2011-03-12T21:09:57-08:00heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 76.112.220.158 | 795 | http | 503